# How to check if JSON data matches a particular string in React js?

Tags: json, reactjs, primereact

I want to check if data retrieved from JSON server matches a particular string in `ReactJS`. I am using `PrimeReact` to draw `table` and `graph` This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {DataTable} from 'primereact/datatable';
import {Column} from 'primereact/column';
import {Dialog} from 'primereact/dialog';
import {Button} from 'primereact/button';
import {Chart} from 'primereact/chart';
import './style.css';

export default class TerminalData extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false,
            visible: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/80ao2')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((findresponse) =>{
            this.setState({ 
                jsonData: findresponse.root,
                isLoaded: true
             })
        })
    }

    onClick() {
        this.setState({ visible: true });
    }

    onHide() {
        this.setState({visible: false});
    }

    displaySelection(data) {
        if(!data || data.length === 0) {
            return <div style={{textAlign: 'left'}}>Click any above to view details</div>;
        }
        else {
            if(data instanceof Array)
                return <ul style={{textAlign: 'left', margin: 0}}>{data.map((browseData,i) => <li key={browseData.serialNo}>{'Blocked URLs: ' + browseData.blockedURLs + ' ,Unblocked URLs: ' + browseData.UnblockedURLs + ' ,Other URLs: ' + browseData.otherURLs}</li>)}</ul>;
            else
                return <div style={{textAlign: 'left'}}>Selected user: {data.blockedURLs+ ' - ' + data.UnblockedURLs + ' - ' + data.otherURLs }</div>
        }
    }

    render() {
        let sarjapur=0,kodathi=0,ec=0,whitefield=0;

        const barData = {
            labels: ['Sarjapur', 'Kodathi', 'EC', 'WhiteField'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Dataset',
                    backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
                    data: [sarjapur,kodathi,ec,whitefield]
                }
            ]    
        };

        if(this.state.isLoaded === true)
        {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.jsonData.length; i++)
            {
                if(this.state.jsonData[i].location === "Sarjapur")
                {
                    sarjapur = sarjapur++;
                }
                else if(this.state.jsonData[i].location === 'Kodathi')
                {
                    kodathi =  kodathi++;
                }
                else if(this.state.jsonData[i].location === 'EC')
                {
                    ec = ec++;
                }
                else if(this.state.jsonData[i].location === 'WhiteField')
                {
                    whitefield = whitefield++;
                }
            }
            console.log("location" +sarjapur + kodathi + ec + whitefield);
        }

        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.isLoaded ? 
                    <div>
                    <DataTable value={this.state.jsonData} selectionMode="single" footer={this.displaySelection(this.state.selectedUser1)}
                    selection={this.state.selectedUser1} onSelectionChange={e => this.setState({selectedUser1: e.value.user_activity})}>
                    <Column field="serialNo" header="Serial No." />
                    <Column field="userName" header="Username" />
                    <Column field="location" header="Location" />
                    </DataTable>

                    <Dialog header="Chart" visible={this.state.visible} style={{width: '40vw'}} onHide={this.onHide.bind(this)} maximizable>
                        <Chart type="bar" data={barData} />
                    </Dialog>
                    <Button label="Show Chart" icon="pi pi-external-link" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} />   
                    </div>
                    : "Loading... Please Wait"} 
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

See the `IF condition block`

I was checking using `If` condition but it does not work and outputs `0`. I checked individually using `console.log(this.state.jsonData[1].location);` I am getting its value from Json but when i compare it, if condition fails. I also tried it by `setting state` instead of using `var` but same result. Here is JSON data if anyone wants to see `http://myjson.com/80ao2`.

What i am trying to achieve is that how frequent a particular word appears and increase the count simultaneously and according to that draw graph. How to achieve this? OR is it not a good approach? Please suggest a better way if i can do this?

Comment: You're post-incrementing instead of pre-incrementing.
`i++`  =/=  `++i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you are not doing increment properly

```
sarjapur++ // post-increment

change it to 

++sarjapur // pre-increment
```

Comment: damn, little mistake.

Comment: always try to debug step by step will help to solve problem properlly